# Persistant Store and App Update

Tags: iphone, core-data, persistent-storage

I have an iPhone app up on the store which uses core data. Now, every time I change something in my code with relation to core data, namely my managedobjectmodel or my model classes, I have to wipe all my data since I get a persistent store error.

Now I'm finding i need to make changes to my app and I don't want my users to lose all their data. What do I do? This is my first foray into Core Data so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It's versioning and migration that I need to look into, no bother.

Comment: Also do not forget that Core Data on the iPhone has automatic migration for simple changes. Just need to turn it on in the options dictionary of the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` when you add `NSPersistentStore` instances to it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to version your data model. Check out Xcode > Design > Data Model. Then you need to migrate the data to the new model. This can get complicated depending on the changes.

Try this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html).